# Sessions not Persisting Under SSL - Laravel

Tags: php, session, ssl, laravel, quickbooks

I have created a SOAP server in order to talk with Quickbooks through a Laravel route. When I authenticate the user in the Quickbooks server it returns an array of data and logs the user in successfully. Ex.:

```
    {"_token":"sOGtZdfUBIfCvktBqareEePSC9ftgPKAEHCe3zXs","login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc":4,"ticket":"$2y$10$0SC02pDGhmY.b/gsxPJrEe9jc3rmy4d7mxij7OmHz10jes77oPsba"}
```

Once it calls the next method though, the SESSION is not persisted and returns only:

```
array (
  '_token' => 'jZSu0VGCs3SgHM3Em7BnyhHPequCYDxC1Zj0dvs3',
)
```

Through a regular, unsecure, HTTP connection it works just fine and persists the data without a problem. Is there something wrong with my sessions config file that it is preventing that?

```
return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'file',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => array(2, 100),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => false,
```

);

Here is the authenticate method:

```
public function authenticate(StdClass $response)
{
    $criteria = array(
        'username'  =>  $response->strUserName,
        'password'  =>  $response->strPassword
    );

    $ticket_information = '';

    //Login failed - return with non valid username
    $somethingToDo = 'nvu';

    if (Auth::attempt($criteria)) {
        //Create a new ticket with bcrypt
        $ticket_information = password_hash(time() . 'quickbooks', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //Store ticket under session for future reference
        Session::put('ticket', $ticket_information);

        Log::info('Successfully logged in!');

        //Find out if we have anything to process...
        list($total, $lefToProcess) = QuickbooksData::findIfAnythingNeedsToBeDone();

        Log::info($total);

        //Check to see if there is anything to process in the database, if there is than we
        //  return '' otherwise we need to return 'none'
        $somethingToDo = '';

        if ($total <= 0)
            $somethingToDo = 'none';
    }

    $result = array($ticket_information, $somethingToDo, '', '');

    return (object) array('authenticateResult' => $result);

}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I don't know Laravel, however try to set the right domain in your "session config file". The browser limits the access to cookies to the domains they are related to.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using native PHP sessions instead of using Laravel to handle it, and everything seemed to work correctly.